# Moodle admin login access is not working

Tags: moodle

Recently we have installed Moodle on our website http://domain.com/test. When we go to admin URl i.e. http://domain.com/test/login it is getting Login page. We have created an admin access and using the same details to login. It is not able to logged in and not showing any error. It remains the Same Login page.

Can Anybody help to fix this issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Subbareddy

Answer (score 0):

It might have been a change to the salt setting in the config.php

You can easily reset the password though, either from the command line

```
cd test
php admin/cli/reset_password.php
```

Or if you are using myqsql or postgresql

```
UPDATE mdl_user
SET password = md5('newpassword')
WHERE username = 'admin';
```